# Why is the \underbrace off the line?

Tags: vertical-alignment, amsmath

I have the following problem with `\underbrace`:
[image: underbrace]

As you can see, the third underbrace and its comment are not in the line with the first two. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

$\underbrace{\text{A long word}}_{=a}$,
$\underbrace{\text{Another long word}}_{=b}$,
$\underbrace{\text{Word}}_{=c}$

\end{document}
```

Update: It looks like it's because of the `g`'s and not the length. But still: is there a way to make them in the line?

Comment: That's because you have no letter with positive depth (e.g., g, y, p, q,… have depth). You can just add in the last `Word\vphantom{g}`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is because `Word` has no descenders, while `A long word` and `Another long word` both have a descender (`g`). Here are some options:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

$\underbrace{\text{A long word}}_{=a}$,
$\underbrace{\text{Another long word}}_{=b}$,
$\underbrace{\text{Word}}_{=c}$

$\underbrace{\text{A long word}}_{=a}$,
$\underbrace{\text{Another long word}}_{=b}$,
$\underbrace{\text{\vphantom{g}Word}}_{=c}$

$\underbrace{\text{\strut A long word}}_{=a}$,
$\underbrace{\text{\strut Another long word}}_{=b}$,
$\underbrace{\text{\strut Word}}_{=c}$

\end{document}
```

I've overlaid the bounding boxes associated with each `\text` string to highlight its vertical/horizontal scope.

The first option is to provide a vertical strut equivalent to the other descenders (using `\vphantom{<chars>}`), while the second uses a uniform `\strut` across the entire usage.

The same holds for an `\overbrace`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

$\overbrace{\text{A long word}}^{=a}$,
$\overbrace{\text{Another long word}}^{=b}$,
$\overbrace{\text{pop rows}}^{=c}$

$\overbrace{\text{A long word}}^{=a}$,
$\overbrace{\text{Another long word}}^{=b}$,
$\overbrace{\text{\vphantom{A}pop rows}}^{=c}$

$\overbrace{\text{\strut A long word}}^{=a}$,
$\overbrace{\text{\strut Another long word}}^{=b}$,
$\overbrace{\text{\strut pop rows}}^{=c}$

\end{document}
```

This time `pop rows` have no ascenders in them, while the letters `A`, `t`, `h`, `l` and `d` all have ascenders. Choose a representative ascender in `\vphantom`, or use a `\strut`.

In both all instances above it should be clear how the bounding box is adjusted with the struts to properly align the `\underbrace`/`overbrace`.

Comment: `\strut` is indeed the solution!